# Dynamically invoke method

Tags: c#, reflection, code-reuse, reusability

I have a WCF service that exposes a bunch of `[OperationContract]`s that perform operations on collections of various types.

Now almost every *implementation* looks like this:

```
        public void PerformSomeOperation(List<SomeType> someCollection) {
        // store the exceptions that might be thrown during the operation
        var exceptions = new List<Exception>();

        foreach (var item in someCollection) {
            try {
                this.PerformSomeOperation(someParameters);
            }
            catch (Exception exception) {
                exceptions.Add(exception);
            }
        }

        // Throw the exceptions here after the loop completes. 
        if (exceptions.Count > 0) throw new AggregateException(exceptions);
    }
```

So, while the `this.PerformSomeOperation(...)` part changes between the actual implementations, the rest of the skeleton remains the same. Hence the idea to dynamically inject the `this.PerformSomeOperation(...)` part.

What is the most elegant solution to this? Of course I could pass in the method name of the operation to be performed as string in the outer method's parameter list and use reflection to call the method (`.GetMethod(...)`) but I was hoping for some elegant Lambda or Delegate construct.

Comment: What's wrong with passing a lambda?

Comment: nothing wrong with it. I just don't know how. Could you provide me with an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a helper method

```
public void YourServiceMethod()
{
    var collection = GetSomeDate();
    DoWork(collection, item => PerformSomeOperation(someParameters));
}

private void DoWork(List<SomeType> collection, Action<SomeType> itemProcessor)
{
   var exceptions = new List<Exception>();

    foreach (var item in collection) 
    {
        try 
        {
            itemProcessor(someParameters);
        }
        catch (Exception exception) 
        {
            exceptions.Add(exception);
        }
    }

    // Throw the exceptions here after the loop completes. 
    if (exceptions.Count > 0) throw new AggregateException(exceptions);
}
```

Or use an extension method:

```
public void YourServiceMethod()
{
    var collection = GetSomeDate();
    collection.DoWork(item => PerformSomeOperation(someParameters));
}

public class ListExtensions
{
    public void DoWork(this List<SomeType> collection, Action<SomeType> itemProcessor)
    {
       var exceptions = new List<Exception>();

        foreach (var item in collection) 
        {
            try 
            {
                itemProcessor(someParameters);
            }
            catch (Exception exception) 
            {
                exceptions.Add(exception);
            }
        }

        // Throw the exceptions here after the loop completes. 
        if (exceptions.Count > 0) throw new AggregateException(exceptions);
    }
}
```

Throw in some generics (to support all types):

```
public void YourServiceMethod()
{
    var collection = GetSomeDate();
    collection.ProcessList(item => PerformSomeOperation(someParameters));
}

public class ListExtensions
{
    public void ProcessList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, Action<T> itemProcessor)
    {
       var exceptions = new List<Exception>();

        foreach (var item in collection) 
        {
            try 
            {
                itemProcessor(someParameters);
            }
            catch (Exception exception) 
            {
                exceptions.Add(exception);
            }
        }

        // Throw the exceptions here after the loop completes. 
        if (exceptions.Count > 0) throw new AggregateException(exceptions);
    }
}
```

Comment: accepted answer because of (what appears to me to be) the most generic solution (extension method).

Comment: No worries.. the important thing is you got an answer to your question! :)

Answer (score 3):

Why not use [delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288459%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)? These are basically function pointers.

So you have your general DoWork method with an [Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
  public void DoWork(Action<List<SomeType>> myDelegate)
  {
       var exceptions = new List<Exception>();

        foreach (var item in someCollection) 
        {
            try {
                myDelegate(someParameters);
            }
            catch (Exception exception) {
                exceptions.Add(exception);
            }
        }

        // Throw the exceptions here after the loop completes. 
        if (exceptions.Count > 0) throw new AggregateException(exceptions);
  }
```

And then call it with a pointer to your own function `PerformSomeOperation`

```
DoWork(PerformSomeOperation);
```

Now you are able to switch the methods you can use.

```
DoWork(PerformOtherOperationWithSameSignature)
```

Comment: sigh. I wish I could split the accepted answer between you and @jgauffin.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the [Template method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) pattern could be handy in this situation.

You define your base class that contains method skeleton as following:

```
public abstract class AbstractProcessor<T>
{
    public void ProcessData(List<T> data)
    {
        var exceptions = new List<Exception>();

        foreach (var item in data)
        {
            try
            {
                ProcessDataInternal(item);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                exceptions.Add(exception);
            }
        }

        if (exceptions.Count > 0) throw new AggregateException(exceptions);
    }

    protected abstract void ProcessDataInternal(T data);
}
```

Then you should define concrete implementations and override `ProcessDataInternal` method:

```
public class ConcreteProcessor<T> : AbstractProcessor<T>
{
    protected override void ProcessDataInternal(T data)
    {
        // This implementation simply writes data to the console.
        Console.WriteLine(data);
    }
}
```

Client example:

```
AbstractProcessor<string> processor = new ConcreteProcessor<string>();
processor.ProcessData(new List<string> { "Hello", "World" });
```